# Can alert show two parameters at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function bj(numa,numb){
    if(numa>numb){
        alert(numa);
    }
    else if(numa==numb){
        alert(numa,numb);
    }
    else{
        alert(numb);
    }
}
```

I mean, in the above function when the two numbers are equal, the pop-up window appears two values. Can I do that?

Comment: concatenate them....

Comment: `else if(numa==numb){
        alert(numa + "," + numb);
    }`

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate them

```
alert(numa + "," + numb);
alert(numa + "\n" + numb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to display you can do something like the below

```
function bj(numa,numb){
    if(numa>numb){
        alert(numa);
    }
    else if(numa==numb){
        alert(numa + " = " + numb);
    }
    else{
        alert(numb);
    }
}
```

This would display the below if numa and numb were 12

> 12 = 12

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate them:

```
alert('number1: ' + numa + ' number2: ' + numb);
```

Comment: Sure, happy to help.